# All my figma work turn into a black outline

Tags: figma

i do not know how i accidently combined some keys and my colourful work turned into a black outline. I mean everything. I have clicked the undo button but nothing seems to work. Here is my screenshot below[image] Am so sad.

Comment: Happened to me today. But after restarting Figma, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Please press the shortcut key:

- Window: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

Comment: Or use Ctrl+Shift+3 (the OG shortcut for Outline View on Windows)